# add videojs 7 to magento 2.4

Tags: requirejs, magento2, video.js

Hello i want to add videojs to my magento theme. Structure of directory.
config:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "videojs": "js/videojs/video.min"
    },
    shim: {
        "videojs": {
            deps: []
        }
    }
};
```

and inside view block:

```
<script>

define(['videojs'], function(videojs) {
    'use strict';

                   var player = videojs('my-player', {
                    controls: true,
                    autoplay: true,
                    loop: true,
                    preload: 'auto'
                });

});
</script>
```

[image]

In console i have `Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(videojs) {`

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should change `define` to `require` in your block some like:

**example.phtml**

```
<video
  id="my-video"
  class="video-js"
  controls
  preload="auto"
  width="640"
  height="264"
  data-setup='{"techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": 
  "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}]}'>
</video>



    <script>
        require(['videojs'], function(videojs) {
            'use strict';

            var player = videojs('my-video', {
                controls: true,
                autoplay: true,
                loop: true,
                preload: 'auto'
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is the issue solved? If anyone can share the complete code with JS, please? Thanks.